# adapting scapy to identify a specific probe

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to modify the below script to be able to alert in terminal whenever a probe is detected that matches a specific format. The format I want to match is 'KD-????????????????' Can anyone help me out?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -- coding: utf-8 --

from scapy.all import *

unique_probe = []

def Handler(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11): # 802.11
        if pkt.type == 0 and pkt.subtype == 4: # mgmt, probe request
            if pkt.addr2 not in unique_probe :
            unique_probe.append(pkt.addr2)
#####need something here to match pkt.info to a condition e.g. if pkt.info=KD* then
                print "MAC: %s probing for %s possible use of KarmaDetector" %(pkt.addr2, pkt.info)

sniff(iface="wla0mon", count=0, prn=Handler, store=0) # sudo rfkill unblock wifi && sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `list` objects if you want unique values. Use `set` objects.

Second, you may use `Dot11 in pkt` rather than `pkt.haslayer(Dot11)`.

Then, you just need to parse the `Dot11Elt` layers to find the relevant value:

```
from scapy.all import *

unique_probes = set()

def handle(pkt):
    if Dot11 in pkt and (pkt.type, pkt.subtype) == (0, 4):
        unique_probes.add(pkt.addr2)
        try:
            subpkt = pkt[Dot11Elt]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        while isinstance(subpkt, Dot11Elt):
            if subpkt.ID == 0:  # SSID
                if subpkt.info.startswith('KD-'):
                    print "MAC %s probing for %s possible use of KarmaDetector" % (pkt.addr2, subpkt.info)
                break
            pkt = pkt.payload

sniff(iface="wla0mon", count=0, prn=handler, store=0) # sudo rfkill unblock wifi && sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
```